# mysql grouping columns together by name

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I was trying to create a demo to explain how JOINs and ran into some difficulty.

```
CREATE TABLE sample (
  id INT
);

INSERT INTO sample VALUES (1),(2),(3),(4);
```

That's my schema.

```
SELECT *
FROM sample AS s1
JOIN sample AS s2;
```

If you do that you'll get this:

```
1,1
1,2
1,3
1,4
2,1
2,2
...
4,3
4,4
```

At least that's what the JOIN sees. If you try to run it however you get one column who's values are equal to the first column. I don't want that - I want both columns.

I could do `s1.*, s2.*` instead of `*` however I want SQL to use it's own groupings. Reason being that LEFT and RIGHT JOINs don't concern themselves with how you're having the data appear in the output - they concern with themselves with the tables that were joined to the RIGHT and LEFT. And plus that doesn't really scale well. I just want to see what the JOIN sees.

Any ideas?

Comment: What do you want to see?

Comment: What result do you expect?

Comment: I want to see two rows - not one. I could do s1.*, s2.* but I'd prefer not to as I attempted to explain in my last paragraph. Gordons answer explains that mysql combines columns having the same name.

Answer (score 1):

This is a peculiarity of MySQL.  Columns with the same name are "combined" into a single column on output.  I don't believe this is ANSI-compliant behavior.

To demonstrate joins, try this instead:

```
select s1.id as id1, s2.id as id2
FROM sample s1 cross join
     sample s2;
```

This renames the columns, so both appear in the output.  Also, I renamed the `join` to `cross join`.  In MySQL, `join` can be used for either a regular join or a cartesian product, depending on the presence of an `on` clause.  I find this behavior confusing.  `join` should be an inner join.  The cartesian product should use `cross join`.

This seems like a strangeness on SQLFiddle.  When I run this code on SQL Fiddle for SQL Server, I get the same results as you.  However, when I run this code on my local SQL Server, I get two columns:

```
CREATE TABLE sample (
  id INT
);

INSERT INTO #sample VALUES (1),(2),(3),(4);

SELECT *
FROM sample AS s1
cross JOIN sample AS s2;
```

This seems to be an issue with SQL Fiddle.

Comment: Seems like it's a peculiarity of all SQL DB's :( On sqlfiddle.com I tried it with PostgreSQL, MySQL, SQLite and MS SQL and got the same thing every time. I'd prefer not to do s1, s2 because I want to see how SQL orders the table columns - not how I'd do so. I mean, that the cross join would yield s1.*, s2.* instead of s2.*, s1.* is true but I'd just assume SQL tell me that and not hard-code it in.